# Modify all img src tags in a particular way

Tags: php

I want to use [phpThumb](http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/) to resize all images in the content divs of my pages when they are served up to mobile devices.

So in my page templates for mobile devices I need to change all `<img>` tags in `<div id="content>` in the following manner:

```
<img src="/images/image_01.jpg">
-> <a href="/images/image_01.gif">
     <img src="phpThumb.php?src=images/image_01.jpg&w=300">
   </a>

<img src="/images/image_02.gif">
-> <a href="/images/image_02.gif">
     <img src="phpThumb.php?src=images/image_02.gif&w=300">
   </a>
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: You want them wrapped in `<div>`s or in `<a>`s? It's not clear between what you ask and your example.

Comment: I want to do this to all the imgs that are inside the div#content. In fact the main need is the ones inside div#comments which is inside div#content. This is necessary because people can post image links in their comments, so we have no control over the size of the images they post, and any one of the hundreds of pages on the site can have an images added to it by a commenter at any time.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/str_replace) to replace the old `img` tags to new ones. Alternatively, you can use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace) too if you are comfortable with regular expressions.

Comment: `:g/image_01/s//image_02/g` in VIM? Seems more like a search & replace via editor than PHP problem

Comment: @Marc B, yes sure, vim, Notepad++, etc can be used. I was answering based on if OP wants to do it with a PHP script :) since it is tagged as a PHP problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since these are template pages specific to mobile devices I would suggest applying this to the actual template file instead of running some PHP code to transform it each time a mobile device requests a page. Most editors have Search & Replace functionality. And some support Regexes. Utilize this to replace all `/src="([^"]+)"/` with `src="phpThumb.php?src=$1&w=300"`.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are perfectly fine for that purpose. But you can also use "server-side jQuery" with http://querypath.org/ to transform it like this:

```
$html = qp($html);
foreach ($html->find("img") as $img) {

     $src = $img->attr("src");
     $img->attr("src", "new.php...");   // redirect to thumbNail

     $img->replaceWith("<a href='$src'>" . $img->html() . "</a>");
}
print $html->writeHTML();
```

Comment: Mario, that's great. I'm familiar with jQuery, but have not yet managed to get my head around regular expressions. So I'm pretty sure I can nut it out with QueryPath whereas attempting to solve it with regular expressions will drive me to an early grave. By the way, the website is www.skepticalclimate.com. I've volunteered to create the mobile version of it.